# Parsing XML file. How do I strip specific text from variable?

Tags: php, xml

I am using SimpleHtmlDom to successfully parse an XML file, but I am getting some useless redundant data for one item and I would like to delete it before it's added to the database.

The specific part I would like to strip is shown below.  I would like to completely remove everything from `<!-- START CLTAGS -->` to `<!-- END CLTAGS -->`.  The information between the Start and End tags changes slightly from item to item, so just need to strip from Start to End.

```
Some useful information here...blah, blah, blah
<!-- START CLTAGS -->
<br><br><ul class="blurbs">
<li> <!-- CLTAG GeographicArea=nashivlle -->Location: nashivlle
<li>it's NOT ok to contact this poster with services or other commercial interests</ul>
<!-- END CLTAGS -->
```

I guess I am looking for a php function to remove all that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Regular Expressions to remove all the unnecessary data, by using the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function

Comment: @TDave00 : regex is not my strong suit... @Gordon ?

Comment: `<!--.*` That would match everything from <!-- to the end, but not sure how to use that expression with preg_replace.

Comment: @TDave00 : try something like this then: `$data = preg_replace("<!--.*","",$data);`

Comment: `<?php

$subject = 'Some useful information here...blah, blah, blah
<!-- START CLTAGS -->

I think the syntax is messed up somewhere.  Not getting any output.
<br><br><ul class="blurbs">
<li> <!-- CLTAG GeographicArea=nashivlle -->Location: nashivlle
<li>its NOT ok to contact this poster with services or other commercial interests</ul>
<!-- END CLTAGS -->';

echo preg_replace("<!--.*]","",$subject);
?>`

I think the syntax is messed up somewhere.  Not getting any output.

Comment: @TDave00 : it seems like your regular expression is off a bit, try this instead - `(<!--.*-->)`